# Execute a script on window's change

Tags: command-line, scripts, fedora, events

Is there an easy way to execute a script when the active window changes ?
Is there a universal solution for both **Xorg** and **Wayland** ?

My goal is to execute a script that will determine either or not to execute another script when the current window change.

In other words when I change the active window (disregarding the type of event: mouse event or keyboard event, ...) the script should get executed.
*[ The script then verifies the current window name and execute a script if it matches a certain pattern (for instance "is the current window an internet browser ?"). But that part is out of the question. ]*

How would you do that ?
I was thinking about making a polling daemon (every .5s) that runs the script and use `xdotool` within to get the window's name.
But again I wish to hear more ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested, here's how I succeeded to make it working.

I created a script :

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/sh

while true
do
    if [[ "$(xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname)" =~ "Chrome" ]]
    then
        xbindkeys 2>/dev/null
    else
        killall xbindkeys 2>/dev/null
    fi
    sleep 0.5
done
```

I run this script on login, when I switch to a Chrome window `xbindkeys` runs along with the config file `~/.xbindkeysrc` containing the Emacs keys.
It's not very elegant but it works.

Comment: xdotool on Wayland? on xorg, use Wnck.Screen signal active-window-changed.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I don't code but I think it's good information for people who will fall on this post, thanks.